# Using c# driver with documents created in node.js

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The documents in my database were created with node.js.  https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native  I'm using the mongodb c# driver and I get an error when I try to access them.  I guess that the objectid that the node.js driver creates is different from the one the c# driver creates.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileFormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the _id property of class trader.Formula: 'CD2j7m4qDLMowGCXi' is not a valid 24 digit hex string. ---> System.FormatException: 'CD2j7m4qDLMowGCXi' is not a valid 24 digit hex string.
  at MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.Parse(String s)
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectIdSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializati onOptions options)
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonReader bsonReader, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonReader bsonReader, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadFrom(BsonBuffer buffer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
  at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetReply(MongoConnection connection, MongoRequestMessage message)
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetFirst()
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
```

How can I fix this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace trader
{
    public class Formula
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
            MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("trader");
            var formulaCollection = db.GetCollection<Formula>("formulas");
            var formulas = formulaCollection.FindAll();
            foreach (var formula in formulas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(formula.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is from db.formulas.find({}, {name:1})

```
{ "_id" : "9RZuitaJ7uKvrBKbE", "name" : "10d sma" }
{ "_id" : "kjLzXChio8wD2MQcD", "name" : "< 10d mean" }
{ "_id" : "mmjSnHS5L2GztXPLX", "name" : "< 2h mean" }
{ "_id" : "bH5zBEz5CnMFJMnSZ", "name" : "< 2h mean > 0.4 sd2h" }
{ "_id" : "A2joSNeBxPZTJgkGs", "name" : "< 2d mean > 0.4 sd2d" }
{ "_id" : "6jgQvFci3mW5Aijr6", "name" : "< 2d mean > 0.4 sd2d 2h sma" }
{ "_id" : "hHBRtu2nWZiYBdHGq", "name" : "2d sma" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you select some sample documents from trader.formulas using the mongo shell and post it here? It looks like the _id you created from your node.js app is not of type ObjectId

Comment: I edited the question with some results.  It looks like they are strings and I think I just realized why.  I'm also using Meteor.js and the formulas were created in meteor.js and I remember reading that it has some issue with objectids.  Is there a way to get these to work in c#?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep you're right, they're strings.  I'm going to try converting them all to objectIds.